# Why function 'runFunc("keyboard", "mouse")' change only three Classes

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

In this code, I made a function `runFunc(previousClass, newClass)` for changing class but only three classes changes by clicking a button. Why should we click button three times to change all the classes.

```
<div class="parent_class" id="parent">
    <div class="keyboard">1</div>
    <div class="keyboard">2</div>
    <div class="keyboard">3</div>
    <div class="keyboard">4</div>
    <div class="keyboard">5</div>
    <div class="keyboard">6</div>
</div>

<br><br>

<button onclick="runFunc('keyboard', 'mouse')">Change Class</button>

<script>

var a;

function runFunc(previousClass, newClass) {
var i;

var a1 = typeof previousClass;
var a2 = typeof newClass;

if (a1 === "string" && a2 === "string") {
    var a = document.getElementsByClassName(previousClass);
    console.log(a);

    for ( i = 0; i < a.length; i++ ) {
        a[i].className = newClass;
    }

    var b = document.getElementsByClassName(newClass);
    console.log(b);
    console.log("\n\n")
}
}

</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because when you are replacing classname in first element it's automatically removed from the list, so the "old" second element become now first, but your loop advances forward and skips "old" second element and so on.
So what you can do is simply keep changing classname in first element until the list is empty:

```js
var a;

function runFunc(previousClass, newClass) {
var i;

var a1 = typeof previousClass;
var a2 = typeof newClass;

if (a1 === "string" && a2 === "string") {
    var a = document.getElementsByClassName(previousClass);
    console.log(a);
    while (a.length)
    {
        a[0].className = newClass;
    }

    var b = document.getElementsByClassName(newClass);
    console.log(b);
    console.log("\n\n")
}
}
```

```html
<div class="parent_class" id="parent">
    <div class="keyboard">1</div>
    <div class="keyboard">2</div>
    <div class="keyboard">3</div>
    <div class="keyboard">4</div>
    <div class="keyboard">5</div>
    <div class="keyboard">6</div>
</div>

<br><br>

<button onclick="runFunc('keyboard', 'mouse')">Change Class</button>
```